# Cumsum but with maximum number of datapoints

Tags: r, moving-average

I'm looking to create a hybrid of `cumsum()` and `TTR::runSum()`where `cumSum()` runs up until a pre-specified number of datapoints, at which points it acts more like a `runSum()`

For example:

```
library(TTR)
data <- rep(1:3,2)
cumsum <- cumsum(data)
runSum <- runSum(data, n = 3)
DesiredResult <- ifelse(is.na(runSum),cumsum,runSum)
```

Is there a way to get to DesiredResult that doesn't require getting finangly with NAs?

Comment: `runSum(c(0,0,data))`? you can pad the beginning with zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what the `partial=TRUE` argument to `rollapplyr` does.  Here we show this with `sum` and also with `sd` and `IQR`.  (Note that the `sd` of one value is NA and we chose IQR since it is a measure of spread that can be calculated for scalars although it is always 0 in that case.)

```
library(zoo)

rollapplyr(data, 3, sum, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 1 3 6 6 6 6

rollapplyr(data, 3, sd, partial = TRUE)
## [1] NA 0.7071068 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000

rollapplyr(data, 3, IQR, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three alternatives.

```
n <- 3

rowSums(embed(c(rep(0, n - 1), data), n)) # base R
# [1] 1 3 6 6 6 6

library(TTR)
runSum(c(rep(0, n - 1), data), n = n)
# [1] NA NA  1  3  6  6  6  6 # na.omit fixes the beginning

library(zoo)
rollsum(c(rep(0, n - 1), data), k = 3, align = "right")
# [1] 1 3 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Thanks @Julius this is great. I would love to be able to use TTRs other functions such as `runSD` too, but it seems the 0 padding technique wouldn't work there?

Comment: True, it wouldn't work. For the case of `runSD` (and most likely any other function), there exists such `x` that `c(x, data)` would give the desired result, but the definition of `x` would involve `data` itself, so perhaps it's an overkill and some simpler approach is better.